# How to migrate from Google Apps Mail

Tags: email, migration, g-suite

I want to migrate some Google Apps accounts to a local mail server. Are there any scripts available, for free or money, which do solve that problem? I will have to migrate about 30 mail accounts this way, a simple IMAP copy via my mail client won't do here.

Comment: Could you explain in more detail the problem you're having, and what steps you've taken to try and solve it. Some clarity on the method you're using and why IMAP copy isn't suitable would also be useful.

Comment: Sorry for replying so late. The problem with Gmail is that every mail has a label, All Mail. Every mail, received and sent ones have this label. When I copy mails from a Gmail account to a regular IMAP server every mail I ever sent or received would be in my inbox. There is no way to differentiate between received and sent mails without Googles backend.

Comment: There is a number of mail filtering/sorting tools that can check headers and/or bodies of messages and then deliver them f.e. into the appropriate folder of the maildir. The exact solution depend on the mail software you have migrate to.

Comment: Did you ever find a good solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this a google apps account?  You can request entire mbox archives of user's email accounts.

The API: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-audit/?csw=1

Command line tool: https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-manager/

I wish this were available via Google Takeout, but it isn't.

Comment: @ulf  How goes the battle?

Answer (score 0):

Check out imapsync...it's like rsync, but for IMAP mailboxes. You'll need to build a text document with each user's credentials, for both their google account and the destination account.

http://imapsync.lamiral.info/